# How to set a "Edge/chrome Browser app" as a default applicationo for a file extension

Tags: windows, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, chromium, default-value

In windows you can choose what application opens which file extension (duh). For instance, a common one is setting Adobe Reader to be the default program to open `.pdf` files.

Edge (or most chromium browsers) have also a functionality where some web applications can be "installed" as pseudo-standalone applications (see [example tutorial](https://allthings.how/how-to-install-any-website-as-app-using-edge-chrome-browser/))

I used this functionality for https://app.diagrams.net/, which saves diagrams with `.drawio` extension. However if I want to open a `.drawio` file, I must open it from the app itself, I can't double click the file and have it opened by this "web app".

Is there a way to associate this extension with this web app so it opens automagically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your requirement can not be achieved.

After testing, I found that you can't even find the `drawio` file type in `windows default apps` setting. Therefore, such `drawio` file cannot be recognized by default, and only after [drawio-desktop](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio-desktop/releases/tag/v15.7.3) is installed, it can be opened in this application.

I also tried the `create shortcute` you mentioned, but it also doesn't work. Edge/chrome can only parse it as XML data and display it on the page. So I suggest you can use drawio-desktop to open/process it as I mentioned above.

You can also create a shortcute of the [diagrams.net](https://www.diagrams.net/)
 and drag the `drawio` file to the page when opening this page.